# strncat causes buffer overflow

Tags: c, concatenation, c-strings, function-definition

how can I use `strncat` with heap objects?

Im trying to write a simple function to concatenate 2 strings together returning the result, however, I can not run it without making the return buffer very large (adding approximately an additional 5000 to its length) for it to not overflow.

I'm probably just using the `strncat` function incorrectly using heap objects instead of character arrays of fixed length. but I don't know how I would write it any other way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *concatStrings(char *arg1, char *arg2) {
    char *ret = malloc(strlen(arg1) + strlen(arg2));
    strncpy(ret, arg1, strlen(arg1));
    strncat(ret, arg2, strlen(arg2));
    ret[strlen(arg1)+strlen(arg2)] = '\0';
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 3) {
        char *print = concatStrings(argv[1], argv[2]);
        printf("\n%s", print);
        free(print);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must `malloc(len+1)` to account for the `0-byte`. And why do you use `strncpy` and `strncat` here with a hardcoded length?

Comment: Look into `snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s%s", arg1, arg2);` to (maybe) replace your `strcpy(...); strcat(...);`

Comment: `strncat` with `strlen` as argument is completely pointless. `strncat` in general is one of those dangerous functions that should be avoided, just like `strncpy`.

Comment: @SpeedrunnerG55: you are not supposed to *fix* the code in the question as it makes comments and answers inconsistent.

Comment: @chqrlie right, I just noticed some glaring flaws in it that were unrelated to my issue. I kept the primary issue in tho, so it should still overflow

Comment: Using `strncpy` with `strlen(arg1)` is not only pointless. It is worse than that. It not only does not provide any extra check, it actively omits the terminating 0 byte as it is not included in `strlen`. The result is not a valid string and when you use `strncat` afterwards you cause undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters the function should be declared like

```
char * concatStrings( const char* arg1, const char* arg2 );
```

because the strings pointed to by the pointers `arg1` and `arg2` are not being changed within the function.

In this memory allocation

```
char *ret = malloc(strlen(arg1) + strlen(arg2));
```

you forgot to reserve memory for the null terminating character `'\0'`. You have to write

```
char *ret = malloc( strlen(arg1) + strlen(arg2) + 1 );
```

Using the magic number 10 in this call

```
strncpy(ret,arg1,10);
```

does not make a sense.

If instead you will write for example

```
strncpy(ret,arg1,strlen(arg1));
```

then the next call

```
strncat(ret,arg2,strlen(arg2));
```

will invoke undefined behavior because the call `strncpy` did not append the null terminating character '\0' to the string pointed to by the pointer `ret`.

It would be much better just to write at least

```
strcpy( ret, arg1 );
```

In any case your function implementation is inefficient. For example there are two times called the function `strlen` for the parameter arg2

```
char *ret = malloc(strlen(arg1) + strlen(arg2));
//...
strncat(ret,arg2,strlen(arg2));
```

Also the call of `strncat` is also inefficient because the function needs to traverse the whole target string to find its terminating zero.

The function can be defined the following way

```
char * concatStrings( const char* arg1, const char* arg2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( arg1 );
    char *ret = malloc( n1 + strlen( arg2 ) + 1 );

    if ( ret != NULL )
    {
        strcpy( ret, arg1 );
        strcpy( ret + n1, arg2 );
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char * concatStrings( const char* arg1, const char* arg2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( arg1 );
    char *ret = malloc( n1 + strlen( arg2 ) + 1 );

    if ( ret != NULL )
    {
        strcpy( ret, arg1 );
        strcpy( ret + n1, arg2 );
    }

    return ret;
}

int main(void) 
{
    const char *argv1 = "Hello ";
    const char *argv2 = "World!";
    
    char *print = concatStrings( argv1, argv2 );
    
    if ( print != NULL ) puts( print );
    
    free( print );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```

It would be even better to substitute the first call of `strcpy` for `memcpy` within the function. That is the function can also look like

```
char * concatStrings( const char* arg1, const char* arg2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( arg1 );
    char *ret = malloc( n1 + strlen( arg2 ) + 1 );

    if ( ret != NULL )
    {
        memcpy( ret, arg1, n1 );
        strcpy( ret + n1, arg2 );
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: i forgot I left the 10 in there, tho in my actual implementation it made no difference, I forgot to remove it from the more generalized function I wrote here

Answer (score 3):

The first problem is, that you don't allocate enough memory, because in C a string is terminated by a `0-byte` so it should be

```
char *ret = malloc((strlen(arg1) + strlen(arg2))+1);
```

And of couse you should check if malloc worked.

```
if (!ret)
    // error
```

The second problem is, that you use `strncpy` with a hardcoded length here.
Just use `strcpy` because you already allocated enough memory.
You can also use `strcat` for the same reason. `strncat` doesn't provide any additionaly benefit, and in fact makes the code slower because you, again, call `strlen`.

This

```
ret[10 + strlen(arg2)] = '\0';
```

is not needed at all. In fact its potentially dangerous if arg1 is less then 10 characters.

Comment: Another problem is that (unlike `strncat()`) the `strncpy()` function does not write a null termintor if there is not enough room, and that will make `strncat()` misfire. If OP has checked the lengths and (hopefully) allocated enough memory, the length restricted versions aren't necessary - even a liability.

Answer (score 0):

I forget `snprintf` existed and thought I had to use either `strcpy` `strcat` or some other string or memory management function to do this

```
char* concatStrings(char* arg1, char*arg2){
  size_t n1 = strlen(arg1), n2 = strlen(arg2);
  char *ret = malloc(n1 + n2 + 1);
  snprintf(ret,n1 + n2 + 1, "%s%s", arg1, arg2);
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: i probably should just use ``sprintf(ret,"%s%s", arg1, arg2);`` instead of `snprintf`

Comment: Using sprintf or snprintf is inefficient. In fact this is a wrapper around my function implementation with an additional parameter.:)

Answer (score 0):

Problems

1. Not allocating space for the *null character*.  Off by 1.
2. `strncpy(ret, arg1, strlen(arg1))` does not *null character* terminate `ret`, so the next `strncat(ret,...` is *undefined behavior* as  `ret` needs to point to a *string*.

Some alternatives:

```
// Via sprintf
// Good compilers will emit efficient code 
//   and not perform the usual parsing overhead of *printf format at run time
char *concatStrings_alt1(const char *arg1, const char *arg2) {
  char *ret = malloc(strlen(arg1) + strlen(arg2) + 1);
  sprintf(ret, "%s%s", arg1, arg2);
  return ret;
}

// Via memcpy
char *concatStrings_alt2(const char *arg1, const char *arg2) {
  size_t len1 = strlen(arg1);
  size_t size2 = strlen(arg2) + 1;
  char *ret = malloc(len1 + size2);
  memcpy(ret, arg1, len1);
  memcpy(ret + len1, arg2, size2);
  return ret;
}
```